# Syntax error in SQL datetime

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I have created something like this but i get an error.

```
create view _incident_tickets(ddate datetime, dgroup varchar(50))

Select 
  --incident.actie,
  incident.dataanmk as "Aanmaak Datum",
  incident.ref_operatorgroup as "Behandelaarsgroep",
  incident.ref_status as "Status",  
  incident.datumaangemeld as "Datum aanmelding"



INTO _incident_tickets
From incident
WHERE incident.dataanmk >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
AND incident.ref_operatorgroup in ('Automatisering','Informatisering')
order by incident.dataanmk desc

Select ddate1,[00:00],[01:00],[02:00],[03:00],[04:00],[05:00],[06:00],[07:00],[08:00],[09:00],[10:00],[11:00],[12:00],
[13:00],[14:00],[15:00],[16:00],[17:00],[18:00],[19:00],[20:00],[21:00],[22:00],[23:00]

From
(Select dgroup 'dgroup',cast(Convert(varchar(10),ddate,101)+' '+ convert(varchar(3),ddate,108) +'00' as date) ddate1,convert(varchar(3),ddate,108) +'00' dtime 
From _incident_tickets)p

PIVOT

(Count(dgroup) for dtime in([00:00],[01:00],[02:00],[03:00],[04:00],[05:00],[06:00],[07:00],[08:00],[09:00],[10:00],[11:00],[12:00],
[13:00],[14:00],[15:00],[16:00],[17:00],[18:00],[19:00],[20:00],[21:00],[22:00],[23:00]) 
)
PVT

Drop view _incident_tickets
```

but i get an error: Incorrect syntax near 'datetime'. What is wrong with my query and can anyone help me out with this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to @PrfctByDesigns's answer:

- Views cannot update data, nor issue DDL commands such as `DROP VIEW`
- Variables in SqlServer must be prefixed with `@`
- `CREATE VIEW` (and `CREATE PROC`) need to be introduced with the `AS` keyword
- You can't `SELECT INTO` an object with the same name as an existing object (viz `_incident_tickets`)

In agreeing with @PrfctByDsgn's assumption that this query should be a Stored Proc or a [Table Valued Function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) because of its parameters, the below compiles, but I suspect may still have some work for you to do / debug:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _incident_tickets (@ddate datetime, @dgroup varchar(50))
AS
    WITH cte_incident_tickets   AS
    (
    SELECT
      --incident.actie,
      incident.dataanmk as "Aanmaak Datum",
      incident.ref_operatorgroup as "Behandelaarsgroep",
      incident.ref_status as "Status",  
      incident.datumaangemeld as "Datum aanmelding"
    From incident
        WHERE incident.dataanmk >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
        AND incident.ref_operatorgroup in ('Automatisering','Informatisering')
    )
    Select ddate1,[00:00],[01:00],[02:00],[03:00],[04:00],[05:00],[06:00],[07:00],[08:00],[09:00],[10:00],[11:00],[12:00],
    [13:00],[14:00],[15:00],[16:00],[17:00],[18:00],[19:00],[20:00],[21:00],[22:00],[23:00]
    From
    (Select 
            @dgroup 'dgroup',
            cast(Convert(varchar(10), @ddate,101)+' '+ convert(varchar(3), @ddate,108) +'00' as date) ddate1,
            convert(varchar(3), @ddate,108) +'00' dtime 
        From cte_incident_tickets
    ) p

    PIVOT

    (Count(dgroup) for dtime in([00:00],[01:00],[02:00],[03:00],[04:00],[05:00],[06:00],[07:00],[08:00],[09:00],[10:00],[11:00],[12:00],
    [13:00],[14:00],[15:00],[16:00],[17:00],[18:00],[19:00],[20:00],[21:00],[22:00],[23:00]) 
    )
    PVT
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't create a view with parameters ... you should create a stored procedure if you need parameters

Comment: You can name the parameters in a [create view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx). However, they may not have types, and they must match the columns being returned.

Comment: correct ... but they are just column names and not used like parameters like in the example above